# Conserving data types from dataframe to SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a dataframe (originally from a csv)

```py
df = pd.read_excel (r'R:\__Test Server\DailyStatuses\DailyWork10.18.xlsx')
```

I created a dataframe to deal with some null values in the rows. I've also created the table in SQL Server, and defined the column types (`datetime`, `int` and `varchar`).

I'm building an insert string to insert the data into a new table in SQL Server.

```py
insert_query='INSERT INTO [DailyStatuses].[dbo].[StatusReports] VALUES (
for i in range (df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        insert_query += (df[df.columns.values[j]][i]) +','
    insert_query= insert_query[:-1] + '),('
insert_query = insert_query[:-3] + ');'
```

My output is:

```
INSERT INTO [DailyStatuses].[dbo].[StatusReports] VALUES (3916, 2019-10-17 16:45:54...
```

I'm constantly running into errors about data types, is it best to define everything as a str so it's easier to insert into SQL Server (and define each column in the table as a str) and define data types upon extraction later down the road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using parameters but based on the question you asked, you are going to have to deal with each data type separately.

For int values, you'll be fine with them as is.

For string values, you'll have to put single quotes around them i.e. 'a value' and you'll also need to replace any embedded single quotes with two single quotes.

For datetime values, you should use a format that isn't affected by regional settings and put quotes around them i.e. '20191231 12:54:54'

The other alternative (as you suggest) is to bring them all in as strings, and do the clean-up, and data-type changes within SQL Server. That's often a more reliable direction. Again though, don't forget to double up any embedded single quotes within the values.